# Wireshark decode base64

Tags: wireshark

Can Wireshark decode base64 in multiple packets? The base64 is not dealing with auth but is in a DNS packet in the text field. As of now I'm decoding them by hand, one at a time.

Comment: This is a question for Wireshark. They have community forums.

Comment: I respect your ability to flag this question as off topic, but i disagree with the reasoning as to why this was done.
   
 
"This is a question for Wireshark. They have community forums"

If this was the bench mark, then the majority of quesitons asked would receive an answer of just a redirect to the official or community based forms for the subject at hand. Ask a question about metasploit -- redirect to rapid7. Ask a question about aircrack, redirect to community forms for aircrack. ad in·fi·ni·tum

Comment: for what its worth, I ended up having to use scapy to do what I was looking to do - and it worked.

Comment: And, that is what we do, when the question is general enough to do so. For security tools for which there is not a strong community or vendor forum, we do answer them here. We handled many metasploit questions when the rapid7 community was down. It makes no sense for this community to either duplicate what another community has done, or supply answers that merely point to another forum.

Answer (score 2):

Could the Wireshark tools assist you in this task? The list is long but I have found many useful and handy tools from the wireshark tools in the wiki:

[Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools)

Comment: I haven't found anything to provide base64 decoding on this list, but I'm upvoting the post because it's a really useful resource.